# asp.net send data from view to controller and create session variables using that data

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, session

When I log in to system, I have received data through http ajax request, then I need to send data to controller which is sent by response. Then at the controller I need create session variables. But I have no idea how can I send data to controller and create sessions, Because I'm new for asp.net mvc

here is my code,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var user = function (userName, password) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    function loginData() {
        var userName = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();


        var userData = new user($("#username").val(), $("#password").val());
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://enh-cis.cloudapp.net/e.cloud/api/UserLogin/GetUserLoginDetails",
                data: userData,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {

                    if ((data[0] == null)) {

                        alert("username or password is incorrect");
                        window.location.replace("@Url.Action("Login", "GRN")");

                    }
                    else {

                        window.location.replace("@Url.Action("Index", "GRN")");
                    }
                },

            });
        }      
</script>
```

Comment: which data you want to send

Comment: You can create session in the GetUserLoginDetails function it self. Or else call another functions exactly in the same way you have called GetUserLoginDetails function using $.ajax.

Comment: which is sent by server(data in the success function)

Comment: @ Priyank how can I create asp session variables inside javascript

Answer (score 0):

Inside 
if(data.success) 
{
//create one hidden field into root template and  set value of hidden field from data[0] and use that into your view.
}